# Insert without duplicates into new table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert some data from another table into a new one, and there is an instance in which the primary key is repeated. How do I insert it / ignore the duplicate value? This is my insert statement

```
INSERT INTO oltp.Host([Host_Id],[Host_Name],Calculated_Host_Listing_Count)
(SELECT DISTINCT [host_id],[host_name],calculated_host_listings_count
FROM csv.Listings)
```

Comment: `where not exists (select 1 from oltp.Host h where h.host_id = Listing.host_id)`?

Comment: Still gives me a violation of primary key error

Comment: Well `distinct` eliminates dups rows. So you have the same id twice but different values in other columns. How do you decide which one to keep?

Comment: Good point, The 3rd column does have a different value in both of them, I don't really know, i guess i'd rather just keep the 1st one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO oltp.Host([Host_Id],[Host_Name],Calculated_Host_Listing_Count)
SELECT [host_id],[host_name],calculated_host_listings_count
FROM (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by host_id order by calculated_host_listing_count) rn
    from csv.Listings
) t
where rn = 1;
```

If it's a one-off insert you could just eliminate rows by hand:

```
where not (host_id = ?? and other_column = ??)
```